# why is @Parameterized.Parameters called twice?

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, testing, junit

I have this code:

```
@RunWith(ParallelParameterized.class)
public class RoutingResponseShortRegressionOneByOne {

...

    @BeforeClass
    public static void oneTimeSetUp() {
        routingUrlHttpClientWithReRun = injector.getInstance(IRoutingUrlHttpClientWithReRun.class);
        System.out.println("in RoutingResponseRegressionOneByOne:: oneTimeSetUp");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void oneTearDown() {
        //        if (globalSettings.isSaveNewResponses) {
        assertE2eCheckers();
        stateSaver.save(e2EResultShort);
        //}
    }

    //takes the next matrix row from OrganizeTestParameterizedInput()
    public RoutingResponseShortRegressionOneByOne(String routingRequest, CompleteRoutingResponseShort
            routingResponse) {
        initNonStaticFromInjector();
        this.routingRequest = routingRequest;
        this.routingResponse = routingResponse;
    }


    //This is called before @BeforeClass !
    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection getRequests() throws IOException {
        injector = Guice.createInjector(new MainModule());
        initStaticFromInjector();
        initTestInput();
        e2EResultShort = new E2EResultShort();
        return OrganizeTestParameterizedInput();
    }
```

And it runs like this:

```
@Parameterized.Parameters

@Parameterized.Parameters

@BeforeClass

public RoutingResponseShortRegressionOneByOne --> ctor

@Test
```

why is `@Parameterized.Parameters` called twice in a row?

In addition, how can I know `@RunWith(ParallelParameterized.class)` really works? meaning how can I check if the run is in parallel?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?  I'm seeing the same thing.